# Disable file sharing with batch

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have file sharing enabled on my computer and I was wondering, is there a batch code that can turn off all file sharing?

I would prefer if I could disable it via a batch script but any way works besides manually disabling it yourself in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste the following into a text file, then save the file with .bat as the extension.
Enable file sharing:

```
echo off
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes
```

Disable file sharing:

```
echo off
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=No
```

Answer (score 0):

net stop server

from batch or command line should work for you.

net start server to start again.